# What is time complexity of this solution O(N) or O(LogN)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/1-iterations/

Considering this:

```
if (largestHole > (bin.length - i) && subHole < (bin.length - i)) {
  break;
}
```

If the length of the largest hole so far is less than the length of the remaining digits to check it breaks the loop

This line `let bin = parseInt(N, 10).toString(2);` is to convert a number from base 10 to base 2 string, which is what I iterate over.

```
function solution(N) {
  let bin = parseInt(N, 10).toString(2);
  let subHole = 0;
  let largestHole = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
    if (largestHole > (bin.length - i) && subHole < (bin.length - i)) {
      break;
    }
    if (bin[i] === '0') { subHole++; }
    else {
      if (subHole > largestHole) {
        largestHole = subHole;
      }
      subHole = 0;
    }
  }
  return largestHole;
}
```

https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/1-iterations/

Comment: what does parseInt( a, b) do?

Comment: The function iterates through all the digits, so it's O(n) (where *n* is the number of binary digits in the input value). To be O(log n) it would have to be significantly different.

Comment: @YogeshPatil it means parse a using base b.

Comment: @YogeshPatil [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: @Pointy once the largestHole is greater than the rest of the digits, it breaks. Doesn't that count for something?

Comment: No. O(n/2) is still O(n).

Comment: Your algorithm has a time complexity of O(logN) using the uniform cost model. If you define n = bit-size of N = log(N), then this is equivalent to O(n). However, when you denote the time complexity as a function of input *bits*, you usually use the logarithmic cost model. And using this model, the decimal to binary conversion becomes more costly than the for-loop and thus your time complexity is dominated by the `toString(2)` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still O(n). The complexity doesn't take into account of coefficients. Also, a O(log n) function would be something like binary search.

**EDIT:** a simple explanation of a O(log n) alogrithm:
Take binary search for example. You have a number x from, say, 1 to 100, and it's hidden in an sorted array containing n numbers from 1 to 100. You start from the middle of the array, depending on the size of the middle number compared to x, you search the left half or the right half of the array. The process continues recursively, until you found the number.

For example I want to find 5 in [1,3,5,6,7,9,10].
I start from the 4th place. It's 6, and its bigger than 5, so we seach the left half, from 1 to 5. Then, I check the middle position again in the narrowed range, which is 3. It's smaller than 5, so we search the right half. At this point we have only one number left - which is 5.

The search keeps dividing the array in half, so the worst scenario would take log 2 n (base 2 logarithm of n). That's a O(log n) function.

However, as I said, the coefficient of the complexity doesn't matter. For example Bubble sort usually takes approximately (n^2)/2 turns, but we simply count that as O(n^2), ignoring the 1/2 coefficient.

Comment: Please can you explain better what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with O(n) but actually it depends on implementation of parseInt function.

Comment: `let bin = parseInt(N, 10).toString(2);` The parseInt converts a number from base 10 to base 2

Comment: @SeyiAdekoya That statement alone makes the function O(n), because the `.toString(2)` part will iteratively produce the string of binary digits, one at a time.